# Resource recommendation: Tensor Networks

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, many-body, spin-chains, tensor-network

I want to learn [tensor network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) methods for condensed matter systems. I went through some basic papers (i.e. [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2164),[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477)) and come to know that there are many things (i.e. different math, tensors, renormalization groups, entanglement) that I do not know. My current goal is to find the ground state energy and wavefunction of simple 1D spinless chain using tensor networks methods (i.e. matrix product states).

I would really appreciate if someone please provide me a proper roadmap by which I can learn this technique in a systematic way. A map from the basic theory to the coding of tensor networks.

Comment: I've deleted some comments, and would remind everyone that comments are for suggesting improvements to, or requesting clarifications on, the parent post - not for answering.

Comment: @DavidZ You seem to have removed the book suggestion which OP had found very useful.

Comment: @Sunyam Yes, that's correct. Answers to the question should not be posted as comments.

Comment: I think it is better to first have the answer and than erase the comment, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The references you provided are already very solid. For a summary of modern approaches I recommend additional the review [Time-Evolution methods for matrix-product states](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05824). Regarding the coding there are countless libraries. Depending on your coding skills (basically the question is C++ or Python) you can take a look into [ITensor](https://itensor.org/) or [TenPy](https://github.com/tenpy/tenpy) for example. But anyway as a general starting point for tensor networks I would recommend to learn how to perform tensor contractions (e.g. with [tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)) and a singular-value decomposition (e.g. with [svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)). Starting codes for tensor network algorithms like TEBD or DMRG can further be found on [mpipks](http://tccm.pks.mpg.de/).

Answer (score 0):

The following website provides excellent resources for tensor networks which are curated for different goals such as Fundamentals, Types of Tensor Networks, Tensor Network Algorithms, Software, Application to different areas.

https://tensornetwork.org/

As suggested in the previous answer ITensor or TenPy is a good way to start with hands-on learning which is my preferred way of learning.